# Selenium Webdriver- I attempted to select an optionf rom dropdown list but failed. I used the code below:

Tags: selenium

Selenium Webdriver - I attempted to select an optionf rom dropdown list but failed. I used the code below:

```
//driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[7]/div/section[1]/form[1]/fieldset/div[1]/div/div/div/select")).click();
//WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
ClickThis.selectByVisibleText("(1 Icon");
```

When I run this script, the dropdown list is displayed but the text "1 Icon" is not selected. It stopped

Comment: That doesn't look like the entirety of the code.  Also, it would be helpful if you'd include the HTML of the `select`, or a link to the website.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the 'Select' class of org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select ?
So far, its the best way to do Select.

```
WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPath of Select Tag");
Select select = new Select(webElement);
select.selectByValue(Value);
```

Hope this helps!